# Grouping and summing within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the sum of each `type` in my array of `roomList`... Tried out `reduce()` but it is only returning the last `value`. Is there a way to achieve this using `reduce()`... I'm open to other approaches also.

```
let roomList=[
        {value:1,type:2},{value:2,type:2},{value:3,type:2},{value:4,type:3}, 
        {value:5,type:4},{value:6,type:4},{value:7,type:6},{value:8,type:6}, 
        {value:9,type:1},{value:10,type:8},{value:11,type:8},{value:12,type:8}
];
roomList.reduce((acc,obj)=>{
   acc[obj.type]=obj.value;
   return acc;
},{})
```

I'm expecting a result like this `{1:9,2:6,3:4,4:11...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get the last value because you overwrite and not add. Change your reduce code to this:

```
roomList.reduce((acc,obj)=>{
    acc[obj.type] = (acc[obj.type] || 0) + obj.value;
    return acc;
},{})
```

To clarify this line:

```
acc[obj.type] = (acc[obj.type] || 0) + obj.value;
```

We cannot simply do this:

```
acc[obj.type] += obj.value;
```

Because `acc[obj.type]` might not be initialized and therefore return an undefined value. Instead we do `acc[obj.type] || 0` to retrieve the value and if it is falsy use a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could use map to accumulate the values

```js
let roomList=[ {value:1,type:2},{value:2,type:2},{value:3,type:2},{value:4,type:3}, {value:5,type:4},{value:6,type:4},{value:7,type:6},{value:8,type:6}, {value:9,type:1},{value:10,type:8},{value:11,type:8},{value:12,type:8} ];
g={}
roomList.map(o=>{
  !g[o.type]? g[o.type]=o.value : g[o.type]= g[o.type]+o.value
})
console.log(g)
```